# Highcharts and jQuery Ui Tabs not works in IE8

Tags: jquery, user-interface, internet-explorer-8, tabs, highcharts

I have multiple tabs with charts inside, works normal within all browsers except in IE8, this web browser, usually the first tab loads with the graph, but when I open another tab to view another graph, all graphs vanish, leaving only empty tabs.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-1">Premiação/Projeção</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-2" onclick="redrawChart(chartFaturamentoGlobal, '#divGraficoFaturamento')">Faturado em Remessa e carteira por hierarquia</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div id="divGraficoProjecao"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div id="divGraficoFaturamento"></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
    var chartFaturamentoGlobal;

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery("#tabs").tabs();

var segmento = $("select[id*='DropDownListSegmento']").val();
    var gerente = $("select[id*='DropDownListGerente']").val();
    var consultor = $("select[id*='DropDownListConsultor']").val();
    var cliente = $("select[id*='DropDownListCliente']").val();
    var ao = $("select[id*='DropDownListAO']").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "projecao.aspx/apresentarDadosFaturamento",
        data: JSON.stringify({ segmento: segmento, gerente: gerente, consultor: consultor, cliente: cliente, ao: ao }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (callback) {
            chartFaturamentoGlobal = showGraphArea(callback.d, 'divGraficoFaturamento', '', 'Total em litros', 'Faturado em Remessa e carteira por hierarquia');
        }
    });
    });

    function redrawChart(chart, idDivParent) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            chart.setSize(jQuery(idDivParent).width(), jQuery(idDivParent).height());
        }, 50);
    }

function showGraphArea(data, renderTo, simbol, yText, title) {

    var chartArea = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: renderTo,
            type: 'area'
        },
        'export': 1,
        credits: 0,
        title: {
            text: title
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: data.categories,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: yText
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + simbol + jQuery.number_format(this.y.toFixed(2), { precision: 2, decimal: ',', thousands: '.' });
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#666666'
                }
            }
        },
        series: data.series
    });

    return chartArea;
}

    </script>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Have you included [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) ?

Comment: I think the problem lies on this bit: `jQuery(idDivParent).width(), jQuery(idDivParent).height()`. Debug it and make sure they're returning something.

Comment: iamchrisfryer: i using version 1.9.1
Tomanow: yes
MelanciaUK: returns

Comment: It's possible that the onclick is not firing when you think it will, have you tried binding to the activate or create or beforeActivate events? http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Sumit: onclick event works right :(